# apache cordova app with typescript

Tags: cordova, typescript, winjs

I have created apache cordova project with typescript template.
There is a textbox and a button on index.html page and onclick of button I need to display information of textbox on second page.
I've used localstorage and window.location.href to pass the information on second page. But by this my complete page is navigated to second page.
But I want something like in below image.

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPijf.png)

What should I need to try? Can i achieve this using winjs.d.ts? Any working example must be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Build a Single Page Application: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: Hey Bruno, could you please share some demonstration using SPA..?

Answer (score 1):

you can try using Kendo UI Mobile framework which is a Hybrid Mobile Framework.

In Kendo UI - you create a layout, then create your pages. To navigate from one page to another you just hyperlink the pages.

take a look at the Kendo UI mobile demos here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/m/index

if you are using Visual Studio i have authored a VS Project Template to work with Kendo UI. Here is a blog post on the same: http://www.kashyapas.com/2015/10/09/releasing-kendo-ui-mobile-project-templates-for-visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova-taco/

Microsoft has come out with CLI tool called TACO CLI - i have created Kendo UI template for that also. Here is a blog post with more information on this: http://www.kashyapas.com/2015/12/15/kendo-ui-mobile-templates-for-taco-cli/

hope this helps.